# Get all data in a line using recursive function from an array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category_name] => One
            [parent_id] => 
            [children_recursive] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category_name] => Two
            [parent_id] =>
            [children_recursive] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [category_name] => Three
            [parent_id] => 
            [children_recursive] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [category_name] => Three and one
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [children_recursive] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                            [category_name] => Three and two
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [children_recursive] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 21
                                            [category_name] => Three and two and one
                                            [parent_id] => 19
                                            [children_recursive] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [category_name] => Three and three
                            [parent_id] => 3
                            [children_recursive] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [category_name] => Four
            [parent_id] => 
            [children_recursive] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18
                            [category_name] => Four and one
                            [parent_id] => 4
                            [children_recursive] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What I want to from this array

```
One
Two
Three
Three >> Three and one
Three >> Three and two
Three >> Three and two >> Three and two and one
Three >> Three and three
Four
Four >> Four and one
```

What I have tried

```
$category = myarray;
renderNode($category);

function renderNode($node) {
        foreach($node as $cat){
            echo $cat['category_name'].'<br >';
            if(!empty($cat[children_recursive'])){
                renderNode($cat[children_recursive']);
            }
        }
    }
```

And My output is

```
One
Two
Three
Three and one
Three and two
Three and two and one
Three and three
Four
Four and one
```

**Edit**
here is the full array list using `var_export` so you can just copay and paste

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'category_name' => 'One',
    'parent_id' => NULL,
    'children_recursive' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'category_name' => 'Two',
    'parent_id' => NULL,
    'children_recursive' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'category_name' => 'Three',
    'parent_id' => NULL,
    'children_recursive' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 17,
        'category_name' => 'Three and one',
        'parent_id' => 3,
        'children_recursive' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 19,
        'category_name' => 'Three and two',
        'parent_id' => 3,
        'children_recursive' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 21,
            'category_name' => 'Three and two and one',
            'parent_id' => 19,
            'children_recursive' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'id' => 20,
        'category_name' => 'Three and three',
        'parent_id' => 3,
        'children_recursive' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'category_name' => 'Four',
    'parent_id' => NULL,
    'children_recursive' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 18,
        'category_name' => 'Four and one',
        'parent_id' => 4,
        'children_recursive' => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: `var_dump` is useless for representing source data, try to use `var_export`, so the array can be copy and paste.

Comment: @sevavietl I add my array using `var_export` for. see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
function getValues($array, $prefix = '')
{
    $values = [];

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $values[] = $prefix . $value['category_name'];

        if (!empty($value['children_recursive'])) {
            $values = array_merge($values, getValues($value['children_recursive'], $prefix . $value['category_name'] . ' >> '));
        }
    }

    return $values;
}

implode('<br>', getValues($array));
```

Comment: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a561ba875b69835c886569ad529a97bf9d38d7e

Comment: its my mistake. I write return statement inside loop :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php). You need to extend it like this:

```
class RecursiveChildrenIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
{
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return !empty($this->current()['children_recursive']);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new static($this->current()['children_recursive']);
    }
}
```

Having this class you can simply loop with one `foreach`:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveChildrenIterator($array),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST  
);

$result = [];
$current = [];
foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    $current[$iterator->getDepth()] = $item['category_name'];

    if (!$iterator->hasChildren()) {
        $result[] = implode(
            '>>',
            array_slice($current, 0, $iterator->getDepth() + 1)
        );
    }
}
```

Take a notice on `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` flag passed to [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3887042a8471228c9ac62c909a38b93f772b9e88).

**Addition:**

I actually misread you desired array, so to get the one you wanted remove the condition:

```
foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    $current[$iterator->getDepth()] = $item['category_name'];

    $result[] = implode(
        '>>',
        array_slice($current, 0, $iterator->getDepth() + 1)
    );
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a624d30d0a04a4def5bf97c59a12f442939ef4a).

You can read more about [iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = myarray;
renderNode($category);

function renderNode($parent_category_name = '' ,$node) {
        foreach($node as $cat){
            echo $parent_category_name.$cat['category_name'].'<br >';
            if(!empty($cat[children_recursive'])){
                renderNode($parent_category_name .$cat['category_name'] ." >> ", $cat[children_recursive']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in the future, you may want to add some context ( comments ) regarding the code you are sharing as the answer.  FYI